# How to "hang on" to Angular scope variables after authentication via OAuth service (like google)

Tags: angularjs, oauth

Here's the problem I am trying to solve (I'm 100% sure I'm asking the "right" question) in my node.js / angularJS web application:

1. Authenticated members of the app can "invite" anyone with an email address.
2. Invitees can register using google (OAth 2.0) or with their email address and password.
3. In either scenario, it's possible that the invitee chooses to register with an email address (either a google one or one they type in) that differs from the email to which the invitation was sent.
4. I want to associate the two emails, and am having trouble figuring out how to do so.

**My current approach:**

The URL in the invitation email includes a unique parameter which references the email of the recipient.  When that link is followed, I store that parameter using an angular service - the same that I use for storing the user once they are authenticated.

**The problem (or at least one of them):**

When I call the google authentication and it, subsequently returns the user to my site via the callbackUrl, my angular service instance no longer has a reference to the initial invitee's email, which I assume is expected since I the user left the angular application and then returned.  Thus, I can't compare it to the email returned by the google authentication and, if they are different, prompt the user, join them, whatever.

What is the best way to toss that reference I take from the link that first took the user to the site to the other side of the OAuth process?

Or, is there a different approach entirely I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to pass a state parameter in your oath request.  Google then returns the same parameter back with the oath response:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent -> paramater: state